# DOS telnet : connection is ok but I can't see the answer because screen is cleared by the answer

Tags: windows, tcp, telnet

I often need to quickly test a remote or a local tcp listener and I use telnet on my PC

Sometimes I need to see the very first answer but there is an escape sequence in the answer which clears the screen

I tried to redirect but the resulting file remains empty

```
C:\> telnet remoteHost portNumber > .\tmp\result
```

Is there a way to obtain the very first answer ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

ncat (from nmap.org) in verbose mode seems to filter some sequences

```
C:\> ncat -vvv remoteHost portNumber
```